# Retaining array keys after using slice in MongoDB with PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a MongoDB object of following structure:

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("4f5ed7d33c9059a00d000002"),
"data":
{
"0": "data1",
"1": "data2",
"2": "data3",
"3": "data4",
}
}
```

I am using the following code to retrieve sliced result:

```
$obj1 = $collection->findOne(array('_id' => new MongoId('4f5ed7d33c9059a00d000002')),array('_id'=>1,'data'=>array('$slice' =>2 )));
```

But the result of this query does not retain array indexes of array data.

Comment: Sorry for that. have edited the variable.

Answer (score 1):

> You can use the `$slice` operator to retrieve a subrange of elements in an **array**.

What you are trying to slice is a *document* (subdocument). Arrays use fixed positions for the elements, [0..(numelements-1)] so there's no way to keep the "indexes". Unfortunately php's equivalent of a document is an associative *array* hence the confusion.

Comment: Okay. So is there any other solution to this? The reason for retaining keys is because we need the key element to delete the array element later. For eg: I can delete the third element( "2": "data3" ) later.

Comment: you could redundantly store it inside the element, eg: `"2": {id: 2, val: "data3"}`

Comment: Okay.Thanks for the response.